# CRUD front end for mySQL in Wordpress

Tags: forms

I hope I've come to the right place. I want to enrich my Wordpress site with a front end to MySQL database, which I host on the same server as my WP site.

I have actually migrated my (former) MS Access database to MySQL and I do get "table read/write" access to it using wpdatables.

I guess, what I'm looking for is basically a CRUD-interface for MySQL on WP. I'm aware, I could construct that myself with lots of php code etc.

But there must be a way, to use the many form engines (gravity, wp-forms, formidable, ...) and have the nice looking forms display individual table records, allow editing them, and write them back to the MySQL database...

Any suggestions here? I really don't feel like reinventing the wheel.

Best,

Dirk

Comment: As an aside, WP doesn't provide a CRUD type setup out of the box for custom tables, the closest is `wpdb` and raw queries

Answer (score 1):

Tom, I appreciate that WP doesn't provide a CRUD type setup ...

I'm just wondering, whether these nice form-plugins that do a brilliant job in displaying and editing MySQL records of their own making within the WP-plugin-database could not do the same thing to a MySQL database on the same server.

Again, I have been toying around with wpdatatables, and this does a good job for ... tables, which are editable and can be based on MySQL queries for that matters. It's also possible to edit individual table rows in a modal pop-up... but these pop-ups provide nowhere close to the display flexibility that, say gravity forms would be able to provide.

Frustrated at something that seems so possible with WP, being based on MySQL itself.

Also, when it's impossible to do it within WP ... what's a CRUD environment then for MySQL? Something that would be emulate both "Continuous forms" and "Single forms" as they were called on (not so) good old Microsoft Access frontend?